# Count number of times element is inserted into vector

Tags: c++

I implemented a code that counts the number of times an element is inserted into the vector within the range N, and then I print the number that appeared the most and how many times it appeared. But my account is always returning strange values. For example, if I enter the number "123" four times, the cont returns "6". I can not see the error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int N,cont, i, j, elem,a;
vector<int> voto;

cin >> N;
cout << "Enter the values ​​of the vector: "<< endl;
while(N!=0) {
  cin >> elem;
  voto.push_back(elem);
  N--;
  }
  cont = 0;
int s = voto.size();
for(i = 0; i < s; i++){
    for(j = i + 1; j< s; j++) {
      if(voto[j] == voto[i])
      cont++;
      else
      break;

      a = voto[i];

    }
}

cout << "The most voted was" << a << "with"<<cont<<"vote";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: He increments cont while voting [i] is equal to vote [j], then since j starts at i + 1, he will look at the next element at i, if equal, increase cont

Comment: Try to follow up the answer which is posted. For improving performance, I think you should go for `std::map`.

Comment: Alternative: If its use is permitted [`std::map<int, int> freq;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is amazingly effective. Place `freq[elem]++;` in the loop with `voto.push_back(elem);` to keep count. Use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find the largest count in `freq` and you're pretty much done.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems with your code.

- `cont` is never getting set back to 0
- If the duplicates in your vector are not next to each other, you are breaking
- If the most frequent duplicates are at the beginning they are being overwritten by the next set of duplicates

To solve these issues you need a `maxCont` as well as your `cont`.  When counting duplicates compare the current `cont` to `maxCont`, if greater replace it.

Comment: I understood what he meant, I did not really expect him to count all the elements of the first

Comment: Who is "he"?  I'm sorry but I do not understand what you're asking.

Comment: @theSpacebaker I think `he` means you. This message was for me.

Comment: @theSpacebaker I would like to suggest you to post related code also. Textual information is relatively easier to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @theSpacebaker sorry haha, i thought "you" but it was something else.

Comment: @KunalPuri I prefer not to solve, this is most likely a homework problem.  They should be able to solve it from here! :)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure that you tried has a complexity O(n^2). You can improve efficiency while simplifying the programme:

1 Sort the vector (`std::sort`): complexity O(n logn)
2 Loop on the sorted vector to count consecutive duplicates : complexity O(n)

As mentioned in comments, if you are allowed, using `std::map`will simplify the programme further, with still a complexity O(n logn)

Answer (score 0):

With `std::map` and `std::max_element`, you can do:

```
int N;
std::map<int, std::size_t> m;

std::cin >> N;
std::cout << "Enter the values of the vector: "<< std::endl;
while (N != 0) {
    int elem;
    std::cin >> elem;
    ++m[elem];
    N--;
}
auto it = std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(),
                           [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
                                return lhs.second < rhs.second;
                           });

std::cout << "The most voted was " << it->first << " with " << it->second << " votes";
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/x2V5DX)